# Is it possible to select adjacent elements when one always contains a particular tag?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, github-pages

I'm having trouble selecting a particular `em` element. I have a block which looks like this which I use for [photos on my blog](https://alxmjo.com/steens-alvord):

```
<p>
    <em><img /></em>
    <em>This is the element I'd like to select and style.</em>
</p>
```

I'm trying to use CSS to select the *second* `em` element. I know I can use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator): `em + em`.

Unfortunately this also selects every other instance of two italicized groups of text, a situation which comes up fairly regularly (and which I'm currently preventing by putting empty blocks between adjacent groups of italicized text).

My suspicion is that this might be possible given the fact that one `em` element always contains an `img` element, but I'm not sure.

Without using classes or IDs (as this is originally written in markdown and processed by GitHub Pages), is there another way to select and style that second `em` tag?

**Not a duplicate:** Were I trying to select the child of the first `em` element, then yes, this would be a duplicate. But I'm trying to select the second `em` element, and can't rely on selecting every single child `em` with a `p` element as its parent.

Comment: You would need to find *some* point of uniqueness. That can even be the `nth-of-type` on the `p` tag if need be. You would need to provide more code for us to help craft that selection logic for you.

Comment: The challenge with nth of type, at least as far as the p tag goes, is that there may be 1 image on the page or 10. Just depends on the the post.

Comment: @temani-afif Can you reconsider marking this as a duplicate? The question you linked to is unrelated.

Comment: it's the same because you need to first select the *first* em then use `+` .. you will need then two selector, a parent selector and a sibling selector. The first one is not possible thus the duplicate

Comment: here is the selector you need `em:has(> img) + em` .. the first part is not yet supported as said in the duplicate

Comment: and the duplicate give you the way to do with JS/jQuery if you want also. As a side note, the parent here is the `em` not the `p` like you added at the end of the answer

Comment: Are the two em tags not siblings? I'm trying to select the second of those two siblings. In any case, thanks for the explanation.